# SQL comparing date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to compare the current date with a date from a database table.

This code:

```
DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%y-%m')
```

gives me a date like this 2020-10

and i want that this code:

```
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL - 1 month)
```

gets date like 2020-10 not 2020-10-12(some day)

Here is the whole sql query:

```
select count(*)
  from app_tickets t 
 where t.status= 3 
   and DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%y-%m')=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL - 1 month)
```

Thanks for help:)

Comment: Do you want to compare year/month only? use `DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%y%m')=DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%y%m')`.

Comment: Reformat that also `... AND DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL - 1 month) ,'%y-%m')
= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL - 1 month)` ...

Comment: =DATE_FORMAT(...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can make use of indexes

```
select count(*) 
from app_tickets t 
where t.status = 3 
  and t.dt >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - interval 1 month ,'%Y-%m-01') 
  and t.dt  < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: The casting is surely redundant